# CharField with fixed length, how?

Tags: django

I wold like to have in my model a CharField with fixed length. In other words I want that only a specified length is valid.

I tried to do something like

```
volumenumber = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=4, min_length=4)
```

but it gives me an error (it seems that I can use both max_length and min_length at the same time).

Is there another quick way?

My model is this:

```
class Volume(models.Model):
    vid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    jid = models.ForeignKey(Journals, db_column='jid', null=True, verbose_name = "Journal")
    volumenumber = models.CharField('Volume Number')
    date_publication = models.CharField('Date of Publication', max_length=6, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'volume'
        verbose_name = "Volume"
        ordering = ['jid', 'volumenumber']
        unique_together = ('jid', 'volumenumber')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (str(self.jid) + ' - ' + str(self.volumenumber))
```

What I want is that the `volumenumber` must be exactly 4 characters.

I.E.
if someone insert '4b' django gives an error because it expects a string of 4 characters.

So I tried with

```
volumenumber = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=4, min_length=4)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x70feb0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 131, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 58, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 74, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Giovanni/src/djangoTestSite/../djangoTestSite/journaldb/models.py", line 120, in <module>
    class Volume(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Giovanni/src/djangoTestSite/../djangoTestSite/journaldb/models.py", line 123, in Volume
    volumenumber = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=4, min_length=4)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_length'
```

That obviously doesn't appear if I use only "max_length" OR "min_length".

I read the documentation on the django web site and it seems that I'm right (I cannot use both together) so I'm asking if there is another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

CharField database model field instances only have a `max_length` parameter, as indicated in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield). This is probably because there is only a max character length contraint equivalent in SQL.

[Form Field CharField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) objects, on the other hand, do have a `min_length` parameter. So you'd have to write a custom ModelForm for this specific model and override the default admin model form with the custom one.

Something like that:

```
# admin.py

from django import forms

...

class VolumeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    volumenumber = forms.CharField(max_length=4, min_length=4)

    class Meta:
        model = Volume


class VolumeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = VolumeForm

...

admin.site.register(Volume, VolumeAdmin)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could write a custom validator that throws a ValidationError if the length is not 4 - this way, the database will never contain an incorrect length, even if they're not using your VolumeForm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: it will generate varchar, not char (in mysql flavor). Fixed char is faster than varchar.

Answer (score 124):

Kind of along the same lines as above, but for what it's worth you could also go ahead with MinLengthValidator which django supplies. Worked for me. The code would look something like this:

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
...
class Volume(models.Model):
volumenumber = models.CharField('Volume Number', max_length=4, validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)])
...
```

Comment: Correct answer! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator

Comment: Up-to-date link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator

Answer (score 102):

You don't even have to write a custom one. Just use the `RegexValidator` which Django supplies.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{4}$', message='Length has to be 4', code='nomatch')])
```

From the Django Docs: [`class RegexValidator(\[regex=None, message=None, code=None\])`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#regexvalidator)

`regex`: A valid regular expression to match. For more on regex in Python check this excellent HowTo:
http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

`message`: The message returned to the user in case of failure.

`code`: error code returned by ValidationError. Not important for your usage case, you can leave it out.

Watch out, the regex suggested by me will allow any characters including whitespace. To allow only alphanumeric characters, substitute the '.' with '\w' in the regex argument. For other requirements, ReadTheDocs ;).

Comment: prefer this to the accepted answer because it ensures correct length even if user is not using VolumeForm

Comment: @tBuLi I trying to allow only digits and changed regexp to ^\d{5}$ but it doesn't work. I can save model with any chars MyModel(myfield='idsj is').save()

Comment: for allow only alphanumeric use: regex='^\w+$'

Answer (score 17):

You can write a custom Validator as suggested by @Ben. As of the date of this answer the instructions for doing this can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/

The code would be something like this (copying from the link):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_length(value,length=6):
    if len(str(value))!=length:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not the correct length' % value)

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    constraint_length_charField = models.CharField(validators=[validate_length])
```

Comment: No need to implement your custom min length validator use: `from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator`

Comment: Thanks to  Pran Kumar Sarkar. the small and the best answer. No need for a custom Validator.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation using [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction):

```
from django.core.validators import BaseValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class FixedLengthValidator(BaseValidator):
    message = 'Ensure this value has %(limit_value)d character (it has %(show_value)d).'
    code = 'length'

    def compare(self, a, b):
        return a != b

    def clean(self, x):
        return len(x)


class FixedLengthCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, length, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        kwargs['max_length'] = length
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.validators.insert(0, FixedLengthValidator(length))

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        del kwargs['max_length']
        kwargs['length'] = self.length
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```