# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_length'

Tags: django, django-models

I get the bellow error:

```
...
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/QIYUN/Project/officialWeb/frontend/models.py", line 93, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/QIYUN/Project/officialWeb/frontend/models.py", line 97, in User
    phone = models.CharField(min_length=11, max_length=11)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_length'
```

My Model code is below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    phone = models.CharField(min_length=11, max_length=11) # this is the line 97 
    email = models.EmailField()
    qq = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)  
    id_card = models.CharField(min_length = 18, max_length=18)
    id_card_img_front = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    id_card_img_back = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Why I get that error? 
And by the way if there is a better way to constraint the phone length to `11`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error suggest, `CharField` does not have a `min_length` option. You can use [`MinLengthValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator) instead

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

class User(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[MinLengthValidator(11)])
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way is there a better way to constraint the CharField length to `11`?

Comment: @aircraft for fixed length, you can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470760/django-charfield-with-fixed-length-how

Comment: This is the simplest way I could think of. Since you want the length to be exactly 11, you could [write your own validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#writing-validators) with a more specific error message.

Answer (score 1):

CharField database model field instances only have a max_length parameter. This is probably because there is only a max character length contraint equivalent in SQL.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class User(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{11}$', message='Length has to be 11', code='nomatch')])
```